# Selecting a vacuum pump for medium/low vaccum (~1000Pa)?

Tags: process-engineering, vacuum-pumps

I have selected a lot of pumps/fans/compressors, but for low to medium vacuum (~1000Pa) the [kinetic theory of gasses dominates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases) and additionally there are many different types of less encountered pump technologies to select from.

How would you select a pump for pure water vapor (steam) at 500Pa being pumped at 1 liter/second up to 1500Pa?

Starting temperature can be STP 273K. I don't need to know an exact pump, I just need some background on the thought process from someone with experience working in this pressure regime.

This [Vac Aero website](https://vacaero.com/information-resources/vacuum-pump-technology-education-and-training/1039-an-introduction-to-vacuum-pumps.html) has a good overview of some pump types.

Here are some pumps I have considered that don't have high oil emissions:

1. [Rotary lobe pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobe_pump) ([Roots blower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roots_blower))
2. [Scroll vacuum pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_compressor)
3. [Molecular drag pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_drag_pump)

.....

Answer (score 0):

1000 Pa (10 mbar) is a pretty weak vacuum, and almost any off the shelf vacuum pump could easily attain it, as long as it is sized for the flowrate.  You will probably need to throttle the flow with a needle valve, either pulling in ambient air, or a parallel stream of steam, to dial in the vacuum level required.  Otherwise it may exceed your desired vacuum range.

Comment: It is going from a vacuum to a vacuum; a side stream would contaminate and defeat the purpose of having the pump. The displacement vs power is not the same as pumping up to atmospheric. While any pump type might work it would be helpful to have an expert in this field to explain why one is used over the other in certain situations.